# Update website(s) similar functionality as used by Wordpress and others

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, asp-classic

We have developed a CMS based website builder.  It is currently available only in asp/ms-sql.  A php/mysql version is in production now.

One critical thing that we are missing is a way to notify users of this software about an available update and a simple "one-click" solution to installing the update.

The update could be something as simple as correcting a typo or as complex as adding a new feature which would entail new pages in the CMS, changes to the public pages and changes to an existing DB table or the addition of a new table.

The question proposed is... Where do we even begin to find information regarding the implementation of an update?

Hope someone here can point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an administrator logs in, the site sends a HTTP request (using CURL from the server, or JSONP from within the browser) to the update server with it's current version. The update server replies with 'there is a newer version: 2.0.1.1.2' or 'no update available'.

On hitting update, replace core files and adjust the database by `ALTER TABLE` statements.
Ensure you have the file permissions to write em with the www user.

You should build the software a way that you have files which do not get edited by the user and files with only user content. So you can replace the core files without worrying to replace any user content. User config files need special treatment.

It's not that hard so I hope my suggestion helps.

Just make sure you have a very strict API and code, so it works for all customers, no regard of operating system and environment, it's difficult to change things later.

I also suggest using SSL for the communication.

Comment: I'd use checksums across the changed files too, fetched from the server.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. **1)** I know nothing about CURL or JSONP (guess it's time I learned though)  **2)** I know how to write the code for altering and/or adding a table.  **3)** Permissions are easy enough to set with one exception... the Index file in the root. **4)** All user content is stored in the DB (files are not editable). **5)** The "update server" could just be a site with the files necessary to reply to the HTTP request and store the newer/updated files... correct?

Comment: All this is correct, except setting permission for index file, goes the same as for all other files. JSONP is, when you include a JavaScript from a foreign server and put your arguments (in this case the version information) into the Request arguments. In return you get a JSON with the results (the newest version available). It's easier than it sounds!